# nest project takes too long to build - heap out of memory error

Tags: npm, nestjs

I have a nestjs project which throws the heap out of memory error everytime I try to

```
npm run build
```

or

```
sudo npm run start:dev
```

I tried increasing the "max_old_space_size" and increase physical RAM to 8GB. No luck so far. If I build it on a different system and run it in mine, it works. It's the build stage that is taking too much time. My project connects to remote mongodb databases using a tunnel.

Here is a SS of the error -

[image]

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

```
Files:                         1196
Lines:                       673815
Nodes:                      3669054
Identifiers:                 750618
Symbols:                     827790
Types:                           76
Memory used:               1047699K
Assignability cache size:         0
Identity cache size:              0
Subtype cache size:               0
Strict subtype cache size:        0
I/O Read time:                0.37s
Parse time:                   3.32s
Program time:                 4.62s
Bind time:                    1.91s
Total time:                   6.53s
```

Comment: I have to wonder what's being done that's taking 2MB+ of memory just to build the application. Is it a rather large server?

Comment: try to run `./node_modules/.bin/tsc --extendedDiagnostics` and show us the output

Comment: I edited the question with the diagnostics @MicaelLevi

Comment: I was able to reduce my memory usage to half by removing some dev dependencies and the heap error has been taken care of too. I will post my changes soon.

Comment: Could you please post your changes? I am too running into this issue with my NestJS Project.